# How do you find the sum of these two sets of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

$V = \mathbb{R}^3$, $U = \begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x,\\ 
y,\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} : x + y = z \end{Bmatrix}$, $W = \text{span} \begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1,\\ 
2,\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{Bmatrix}$

*Is    V = U + W?*

Good day everyone.

Here's a example question from my lecture notes. The solution given is as follows:

$U = \begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x,\\ 
y,\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}:
\begin{pmatrix}
1, & 1, & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x,\\ 
y,\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix} = 0 \end{Bmatrix}$

$U = \text{span} \begin{Bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-1,\\ 
1,\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1,\\ 
0,\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} \end{Bmatrix}$

$\dim U = 2$

$b1 = \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}, b2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}, b3 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

(b is a basis of U, so now we do Guassian elimination)

$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &1  &1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2\\ 
0 & 1 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$

...

$\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &1  &1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3\\ 
0 & 0 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$

We now have 3 pivot columns.

(The notes don't go any further than this, and I am unsure on what answer it concludes with)

So, simply put, I don't really understand the majority of this solution. I understand that the span of U is represented by two vectors which aren't scalars of one another, and so are linearly independent, meaning they're also a basis, so we know that the dimension of U is 2. I also know how to do Guassian elimination, but the rest is a bit of a blur. If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated! :)

(Also, apologies for the rushed latex. I tried. I hope it's understandable enough.)

Comment: so after gaussian elimination, you have effectively proven these bi's are linearly independent. As it in total has dimension of 3 and it is a subspace of V, they must be equal. So the answer is yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notice that $U$ is a plane because it is defined by a linear non-trivial polynomial equation $ax + by + cz = 0$ (in linear algebra terms, it is the orthogonal complement to ${\rm span}((a,b,c)) \neq \{0\}$). So $U$ has dimension $2$. Moreover, the vector $(1,2,0)^T$ does not belong to $U$, and then so does not any of its multiples. It is also non-zero, so $\dim(W) = 1$ and $U \cap W = \{ 0 \}$. By Grassmann, $\dim(U \oplus W) =\dim(U) + \dim(W) = 1 + 2 = 3$, so that $U \oplus W = \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the response! 

I'm just a bit confused with the last line. Let's say a vector space U has dimension n, does that mean U is "equivalent" to R^n?

Comment: @Anonymous73648 yes. If by equivalence you mean isomorphism, every two finite dimensional vector spaces with the same dimension $n$ over the same field $\mathbb{k}$ are isomorphic. Just order a basis of each and construct the map that to the $i$-th element of the basis of the first vector space associates the $i$-th element of the basis of the second vector space. By determination of a linear application on a basis, there is a unique linear map extending this map. You can check this is injective and surjective.

Comment: I understand the first half of what your comment, but not the second. What exactly does this map represent? What does extending the map show? Why is it useful in showing the two spaces are isomorphic? And in what way are isomorphic vector spaces equal? Sorry if that's an overwhelming amount of questions. I'd just like to get a handle on this.

Comment: @Anonymous73648 say $V$ and $W$ are two vector spaces over $\mathbb{k}$, $\dim_{\mathbb{k}}(V) = \dim_{\mathbb{k}}(W) = n < \infty$. Pick a basis $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$ of $V$ and a basis $\{ w_1, \ldots, w_n \}$ of $W$. Define the map $\phi: V \to W$ such that $\phi(\lambda_1 v_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n v_n) = \lambda_1 w_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n w_n$ and the map $\psi: W \to V$ such that $\psi(\mu_1 w_1 + \cdots + \mu_n w_n) = \mu_1 v_1 + \cdots + \mu_n w_n$. Notice this maps are linear and $\psi \circ \phi = id_V$ and $\phi \circ \psi = id_W$. They then give an isomorphism $V \cong W$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need so much computations. You can observe that your vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\0\end{pmatrix}$ does not belong to $U$, and so also any proportional vector of it does not belong to $U$, since $U$ is a vector space. Therefore, $U$ and $W$ are in direct sum. By Grassman formula you can deduce that the dimension of the sum is $2+1-0=3$, that is the dimension of the ambient space. This means $\mathbb R^3=U\oplus W$.